# import a single node and all its comment from one DB to another DB

Tags: migrations, importing-exporting

Accidently, a node(forum topic) and all its comment got deleted. The deleted data is available in local environment and now I want to export/migrate that data to live enviroment again. Plz suggest me some solution to migrate that data to live enviroment again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You delete manually a row from a table? Please give more information. You can always recover manually using MySQL.

Comment: Why didn't you restore from backup immediately? Now it'll be a lot harder.